# I'm trying to make this sql Update query but I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I can't understand why this query doesn't work... I putted the query in an if with an echo to see if it returns true and he does! But if I go to see if the sql table, it hasn't been updated... Can someone help me?

This is the code:

```
$rowpost='';
if(isset($_POST['rowpost'])){
$rowpost  = $_POST['rowpost'];
$rowpost  = implode(' ', $rowpost);
  if(mysql_query("UPDATE prodotti SET vetrina='$rowpost' WHERE id='$_GET['id']'")){
    echo 'rowpost';
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['addrowname'])){
$filename = "showcase.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$newcontent = $contents.' '.$_POST['addrowname'];
fwrite(fopen($filename, 'w'), $newcontent);
if(isset($_POST['chkaddshcs'])){
  $rowpost  = $_POST['addrowname'].' '.$rowpost;
  if(mysql_query("UPDATE prodotti SET vetrina='".$rowpost."' WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'")){
    echo 'chkaddshcs';
  }
}
```

It doesn't give errors, it says rowpostchkaddshcs but he doesn't update the table...

Comment: Just to make shure:Did You open a connection to the database? And i recommend you to use mysqli instead of mysql. Mysql is deprecated

Comment: Yes, I did, this is only a part of the code

Comment: Have you tried to echo `"UPDATE prodotti SET vetrina='$rowpost' WHERE id='$_GET['id']'"`? If so what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Stop using `mysql_*`functions since they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` instead. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for reference.

Also, your code is in danger of SQL-Injection. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) for reference, also.

---

About your specific problem:

This line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE prodotti SET vetrina='$rowpost' WHERE id='$_GET['id']'")
```

You must remove the single quotes around id, or add curly braces.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE prodotti SET vetrina='$rowpost' WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'")
```

OR

```
mysql_query("UPDATE prodotti SET vetrina='$rowpost' WHERE id='$_GET[id]'")
```

Comment: Yes I know, before this there is a $_SESSION control: only website admin can access to this page so I didn't worried about sql injection